# duda sobre Vectores

Tags: c++

Al resolver este problema

> Haz una función con cabecera
>
> vector aplana(const vector< vector >& v); que recibe varios
>   vectores y los concatena por orden. Por ejemplo, si la función recibe
>   el vector de vectores
>
> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] debe devolver el vector
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

con el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> aplana(const vector< vector<int> >& vv){
    vector<int> x;
    //vv[i][j]
    for(int i = 0; i< int(vv.size());i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < int(vv[i].size());j++){
            x.push_back(vv[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int main(){
    vector< vector<int> >vv(3);//V ector de V ectores

    vv[0].push_back(1);
    vv[0].push_back(2);
    vv[0].push_back(3);

    vv[1].push_back(4);
    vv[1].push_back(5);

    vv[2].push_back(6);
    vv[2].push_back(7);
    vv[2].push_back(8);
    vv[2].push_back(9);

    vector<int> v(aplana(vv));//V ector

    for(int i = 0;i <int(v.size());i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<' ';

    }
}
```

me ví con la situacion de usar muchas veces la funcion `push_back()` en el código, ya que no conozco mucho sobre vectores y no se otra forma de asignarles valor a las "casillas" de un vector que no sea una por una con `push_back()` o como un `array (vv[0][0] = 1`).

queria pedirles que si me pudieran explicar que métodos existen para valorizar 2 o más casillas de un vector de una sola vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te puedes permitir trabajar con el estándar C++11 (2011) o C++14 (2014) tienes a tu disposición las listas de inicialización. Este mecanismo permite asignar una serie de valores a un elemento sin tener que recurrir a push_back:

```
vv[0] = {1, 2, 3};
vv[1] = {4, 5};
vv[2] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
```

E incluso las listas de incialización pueden anidarse para crear una estructura más compacta:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = { { 1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7,8,9} };
```

Si no te puedes permitir el lujo de usar los estándares más actuales te toca pegarte con `push_back`. Eso sí, siempre puedes hacer uso de alguna función para no tener que repetir tanto código. Un ejemplo tonto:

```
std::vector<int> ToVector(int size, int* datos)
{
    std::vector<int> toReturn;
    for( int i=0; i<size; ++i,++datos)
      toReturn.push_back(*datos);

    return toReturn;
}

int main()
{
  int data1[] = {1,2,3}; 
  int data2[] = {4,5}; 
  int data3[] = {6,7,8,9}; 

  std::vector<std::vector<int> > mm;
  mm.push_back(ToVector(3,data1));
  mm.push_back(ToVector(2,data2));
  mm.push_back(ToVector(4,data3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`std::copy`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) y la utilidad [`std::back_inserter`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), así que suponiendo estos vectores:

```
std::vector<int> uno = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> otro = {4, 5};
std::vector<int> ultimo = {6, 7, 8, 9};
```

Una posible solución sería:

```
std::vector<int> aplanado;
aplanado.reserve(uno.size() + otro.size() + ultimo.size());

std::copy(uno.begin(),    uno.end(),    std::back_inserter(aplanado));
std::copy(otro.begin(),   otro.end(),   std::back_inserter(aplanado));
std::copy(ultimo.begin(), ultimo.end(), std::back_inserter(aplanado));

for (const auto &v : aplanado)
    std::cout << v << ' ';
```

Eso no te va a evitar usar el `push_back` pero al menos *no se ve*. Por cierto, no es necesario usar el [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) pero yo te aconsejo que lo hagas igualmente.

También podemos generalizar el "*aplanamiento*" de vectores creando un operador de concatenado:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b)
{
    std::vector<T> result(a);
    result.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}

for (const auto &v : uno + otro + ultimo)
    std::cout << v << ' ';
```

No es necesario que el `operator +` sea plantilla, pero tal y como lo he planteado yo podrás concatenar cualquier tipo de vector.

Comment: si no es nesesario usar `std::vector::reserve` ¿por que me recomiendas utilizarlo?

Comment: No es necesario abrigarse para salir a la calle en un día frío, pero te aconsejo hacerlo; la ausencia de abrigo no te impedirá caminar pero caminarás *mejor* si estás abrigado un día frío. El uso de `std::vector::reserve` no cambiará el comportamiento observable del código que he propuesto, pero reducirá la cantidad de veces que se solicita memoria, haciendo el código ligeramente más eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

De preferencia pega el código aquí para no tener que buscarlo en otro sitio.

Puedes asignar un vector con una lista de inicialización, de modo que tu código podría quedar:

```
vv[0] = {1, 2, 3};
vv[1] = {4, 5};
vv[2] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
```